# NestJS Create a custom Length validator to work like IsIn where the allowed lengths are passed in an array

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I want to build a custom validator that will work similar to [@IsIn](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/develop/src/decorator/common/IsIn.ts), accept an array of values, which will be field lengths that can be used.  I want to be able to pass an array of allowed lengths to check against.  While I have looked into the IsIn code on class-validator, how to convert this for NestJS is what I am unsure of.

I am trying to validate data that might have a length of 12 or 32 digits (old system, new system), but not other lengths, so the current @Length() is not sufficient.

I need to be able to create a @LengthIn() style validator, where I can use the sizes in the decorator

`@IsString @LengthIn([12, 32]) public readonly PackageNumber:string;`

I am looking to use this in the DTO class for the standard validation.

I do not know how to convert the @IsIn call, to be a NestJS decorator. This is what I tried, but it does not work.

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface } from 'class-validator';

export function LengthIn(property: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            constraints: [property],
            validator: IsLongerThanConstraint,
        });
    };
}

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'LengthIn' })
export class IsLongerThanConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const AllowedLengths:number[] = args.constraints;       // How to I set an array of values?
        let LengthIsGood:boolean = false;
        AllowedLengths.forEach( (Length:number) => {
            if (value.length === Length) {
                LengthIsGood = true;
            }
        });
        return typeof value === 'string' && LengthIsGood;
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not know how to add the code to handle accepting the passed array of proper values, into the ValidatorConstraints.